# Making the element of an array containing double quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

How do you make this the whole lot,

```
<input type="text"/> <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" step="10" value={val} onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)}/> {val}
 <br></br>
```

the element of an array? The problem is it contains double quotes but the element is surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: *"The element is surrounded by double quotes"*: where do you see those quotes?

Comment: you mean you want a string literal containing that HTML content? Either surround it with single quotes, or use double quotes and escape the ones in the string with a backslash.

Comment: You can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single quotes for an array.

```
var a = ['<input type="text"/> <input type="range" min="-50" max="50" step="10" value={val} onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)}/>{val}<br></br>']
```

Comment: Thanks for relpying. The question seems to have been closed. But I have used single quotes as you suggested but it's not working for me. I simplified the element to '<input type="text"/>' and just get that as a string. It won't actually read it at html and render it to the page.